# Google search results shows every page on my site as a separate result

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I'm new to SEO but been working for a while in our own company site, I have fetch and probe everything in the GSC even sent a update sitemap recently, already processed and everything is cool, but when I search in google something like this shows up

[image]

all I want is to have all my site under the same result like this:

[image]

Could you give me some advice on it.

It's worth to say, I have everything check on the search console, my sitemap updated and valid.

Comment: the instructions are here -  https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview - you now have full control over sitelinks, they are not automated and should appear within a few days of adding a small amount of JSON-LD code to your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues going on. The one that addresses your issue most directly is that you do not have a description meta-tag or much content (at least on the home page) and Google is choosing to create your snippet from what it can find which is your first h1 tag and contact information.

You are missing much of the basics in SEO. Here are some links to answers I have written that should help. Please ignore the title of the link and read these answers. There is some overlap in these answers, but read through them anyway- there are little nuggets hidden in these. It will help you to understand what you need to know.

The headline read order:
[SEO on Single Page Website and Content keywords](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71431/seo-on-single-page-website-and-content-keywords/71433#71433)

The importance of title tag length:
[Title in Google does not match <title> of document](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65767/title-in-google-does-not-match-title-of-document/65768#65768)

Title tag effect on SERPs:
[Title tag different from title appearing in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google/69206#69206)

More on title tag effect on SERPs:
[My title tag doesn't appear to be getting crawled by Google properly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69050/my-title-tag-doesnt-appear-to-be-getting-crawled-by-google-properly/69080#69080)

More on the headline read order:
[Improve Google ranking for general vs. specific keywords](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74313/improve-google-ranking-for-general-vs-specific-keywords/74334#74334)

Semantics in search:
[Why would a website with keyword stuffing rank higher than one without in google search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/why-would-a-website-with-keyword-stuffing-rank-higher-than-one-without-in-google/81552#81552)

How URL/URIs effect search:
[Well structured URLs vs. URLs optimized for SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639)

How semantics effects a link:
[Keyword phrases and links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83238/keyword-phrases-and-links/83239#83239)

Where to put contact info:
[Should Schema.org Organization data about my company be on every page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82507/should-schema-org-organization-data-about-my-company-be-on-every-page/82509#82509)

Are bad links toxic?
[What is a toxic link?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83825/what-is-a-toxic-link/83835#83835)

How semantics effects search:
[Can writing a floating navbar's HTML at the bottom of the page increase SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84009/can-writing-a-floating-navbars-html-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-increase-seo/84011#84011)

Pipes in title tag:
[Site URL being displayed before TITLE on SERP](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78011/site-url-being-displayed-before-title-on-serp/78025#78025)

Okay. That is a lot of reading! Sorry. But these are as many answers I could find quickly that would help you to truly understand SEO and get you started and be *jazzed* about SEO (if there is such as thing).

Comment: the sitelinks process has changed and now relies on JSON-LD in the home page, nothing ia automated, see https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview

Comment: @Mousey Thanks! I will check that out later. It also requires mark-up for contact information such as name, address, phone, (NAP) etc. as step one branding signal before Google will even think about site links. That leaves me out!! Staying private. I can still be easily reached if people want to.

Comment: that's no longer the case, it works without address/phone/NAP, took the json-ld plus a few days with 'name' set to the domain name (minus the TL DR). If it validates in the structured data testing tool it will work.example code `<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>`

Comment: @Mousey Cool flippin beans man!! For a while G was punishing sites that did not NAP even though G knows full well who I am. This included G+. I am not a social media guy- got too much to do with the farm, the rental properties, the antiques business, etc. to be engaging people in BS. Do not FB, twitter the twits, comments section, forum, or anything other than hang out here because I love you guys!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The "single" result is known as Google Sitelinks.   New sites don't get that treatment.   Once you site is a year or two old, Google will often switch the display over automatically.

The site links feature is *completely* controlled by Google.   There is nothing you can do to directly turn it on.   We do have a question that addresses what you can do to make your site most likely to get it: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Comment: sitelinks are no longer automated - you can add them with JSON-LD structured data